# Vim's font and resolution are error in Windows Bash Subsystem

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using vim in Windows Linux Subsystem bash.
I had some font configs like this:
[image: Terminal's font settings]
But when I open vim, I finds the font and screen dimensions are wrong:
[image: Wrong font and screen dimensions]
It seems that the settings are overridden by vim:
[image]
I don't know where is the root cause, anyone encounter this situation?
How can I fix this?

Comment: not sure if it's the same problem, but does the solution posted here: https://www.unoiou.com/articles/2019/04/18/time-wasting-stuff/fix-windows-wsl-vim-font-issue/ works for you? (it seems to be the same solution also posted in this WSL github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/757#issuecomment-359867729)

Comment: Yeah~It really f**king works. Thanks a lot, mate.

Comment: great to hear that! I'll add the solution as an answer for future reference and you can mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

googling OP's problem, I found two links that described and solved a similar problem in the exact same way. I asked OP if works even for him and he said yes, so I'm reporting the solution here for future reference.

from a blog post (https://www.unoiou.com/articles/2019/04/18/time-wasting-stuff/fix-windows-wsl-vim-font-issue/):

> Fourtunately, I found a solution by editing `Registry` on Windows 10.
>
> - Add a new `DWORD` record in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\C:_Program Files_WindowsApps_CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2018.817.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc_ubuntu.exe` named `CodePage`
> - Set it to `Decimal` and value `65001` or `Hexadecimal` and value `fde9`
> - Restart the wsl window

from a WSL github issue comment (https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/757#issuecomment-359867729):

> in the (registry) path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\C:_Program Files_WindowsApps_CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_xxxx.ubuntu.exe`,
> add `CodePage->(DWORD)FDE9(65001)`
> then I start `Ubuntu` directly from start menu, It's Consolas !
> PS: I use the new `Ubuntu` distribution from windows appstore, not the old one from Windows Subsystem for Linux